# Blender MakeHuman to Three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, blender, makehuman

I'm trying to integrate a animated 3D character in a Web navigator.

I use MakeHuman 1.02 to create a character which I import in Blender 2.74 in .mhx format.
I retarget to a BVH using the MakeWalk plugin for Blender. It's for the motion.
When I try to export the character in .json format (three.js), the following error appears :
MakeHuman is not a valid mesh object.
A mesh object is an object that we can modify properties or vertices, isn't it ?

I try others format like .dae format (collada) but it seems that the navigators doesn't find the skeleton and the textures of the character (even if they are in the same directory) necessary for the character's motion.

How to get the character like a mesh object ? Or somebody knows another process to success ?

Comment: I've the same trouble, did you found something ?

Comment: In order to export to three.js, you have to select only the mesh, do not select the skeleton.

Comment: @EricaOkamura, I've seen your name on a few other posts recently. I thought you'd be interested in my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Like Erica pointed out, you need to have a mesh selected to export it. The problem with this is it doesn't seem to work if you have multiple meshes. Only one will export. This is a problem when using MakeHuman because their clothes are separate meshes.

One way to fix this is to select all meshes and combine them into one (I believe that's CTRL + J). However, you'd have to somehow merge all your texture files into one big one and I have no idea how to do that.

What I do is to export the entire scene. Then it doesn't matter what is selected. All meshes get exported. You can load it using either the ColladaLoader, which I would recommend since you're retargeting to a BVH (worked great for me), or the new ObjectLoader.

If you have your own Scene object on the page that you want to use, you can still load the scene created by the exporter, traverse it to get the items you care about, and add those items to *your* scene that will display on the page.